# Passing arraylist of objecs through HTML form

Tags: html, jsp, object, servlets, arraylist

So I have a Java ArrayList < myObject > arr that I want to pass from a jsp file to a java servlet using an HTML form. Whats the syntax to pass it?

Comment: It's somewhat arbitrary, since you can't pass objects. As long as you or your framework can reconstruct what you want from the parameters names and values, pick naming and conversion conventions and have at it.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myObject" value="value_of_index_0">
<input type="hidden" name="myObject" value="value_of_index_1">
<input type="hidden" name="myObject" value="value_of_index_2">
<!-- etc -->
```

Alternatively, you could serialise to JSON and place that as the value of a single hidden input.

Comment: So in the servlet file can I do:

ArrayList<myObject> arr = request.getParameter("myObject");

Comment: No, [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)): You should only use this method when you are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).

Comment: getParameterValues() returns a String[], but my ArrayList isn't made up of strings, so is it possible to cast this method to the type of object that I want?

Comment: This will also only return you a `String[]` — you'll then need to iterate over it, casting each to your object type before adding it to your ArrayList & handling any errors. (In reality, you'll probably need some sort of transform method rather than a straight cast)

Comment: @user1782677 The HTML GET/POST methods are only going to send values as strings, so yes, you'll have to cast them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your array list as an attribute on the context,session or request using JSP implicit objects Application,Session, or request and in your servlet get the attribute from the scope that you used in the JSP i.e if you put it in the request then in your servlet you will type `request.getAttribute("Your_Object_Name")`

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Use this method to serialize to a String your object:

```
private static String toString( Serializable o ) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
    oos.writeObject( o );
    oos.close();
    return new String( Base64Coder.encode( baos.toByteArray() ) );
}
```

And then put this String in an inputHidden html tag to be passed in the HTML form.

And now in the Servlet, use this method to deserialize your string to the object:

```
 private static Object fromString( String s ) throws IOException ,                                                       ClassNotFoundException {
    byte [] data = Base64Coder.decode( s );
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( 
                                    new ByteArrayInputStream(  data ) );
    Object o  = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return o;
}
```